# Jasmine spyOn not working for window function

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, jasmine, angular6

I am trying to spyOn on window.alert.I had spied window's alert function but it still says it has to be spied.
 My Component has

```
method1(){
method2();
}
method2{
if(some condition){
alert('hello');
}
}
```

My unit test :

```
it('it should say hello', () => {
 spyOn(component, 'method1').and.callThrough();
   spyOn(window, 'alert');
component.method1();
expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');

}
```

error is
Expected spy alert to have been called with [ 'hello'] but it was never called

Comment: Can you give a working reproduction of described error ? Cause yours code should work.

Answer (score 0):

Because you have spied the method1() and your alert is being called from method2(). So Spying on method2() will pass the test.
The following code should run:

```
 it('it should say hello', () => {
         spyOn(component, 'method2').and.callThrough();
         spyOn(window, 'alert');
         component.method1();
         expect(window.alert).toHaveBeenCalledWith('hello');

    }
```